# Confusing choices for what the limits at infinity for a rational function

Tags: calculus, limits

I was given a question in our discussion that states that:

> Let $$f(x) = \frac{(x^3+2)}{x}$$ What is the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches infinity? The choices were:
> A. It is a relative extremum of $f$.
> B. It is a point of inflection of $f$.
> C. It is a horizontal asymptote of $f$.
> D. It is a vertical asymptote of $f$.

Obviously, D isn't correct.

For A, B, and C, we need a certain value for it to be true, right? Is there something wrong with the question or I'm missing something?

Comment: The limit of f as x approaches to infinity is infinity, so Im having some troubles.

Comment: None of the four choices are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is any of the choices, because I graphed it on Desmos, and there is a vertical asymptote at zero, but it just blows up at both ends of the graph.[image: the graph of f(x)]

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think that any of the choices are the answer, as stated by James, because of L’Hôpital’s Rule. If $f(x)={(x^3+2)}/x$, since $x^3+2$ and $x$ both tend to infinity as $x$ goes to infinity, we can use it. We get that this limit is equal to the limit of $3x^2$, which goes to infinity. For a vertical asymptote, we would need infinities for an x-value in the function’s domain from both sides, and for a horizontal asymptote, we would need the function to approach but never reach some finite value as $x$ goes to infinity. Relative extrema and inflection points both require the function to have its derivative equal to $0$ as x goes to infinity, which makes no sense, because ${(x^3+4)}/x$ goes up to infinity.